# All HTML 5 Video sounds starting uncontrollably in Firefox 44

Tags: javascript, firefox, video

I observed a strange behaviour where Firefox (exclusively) starts playing the sounds of all videos embedded in a page, even though the elements themselves are not playing. Means: If you click play on the video controls a new sound and video playback gets started (as you would expect).

The video elements all have 3 different source files to satisfy all major browsers, as you can see in the code below.

I tried to add `autostart="false"` to the tag and to call `.pause()` on each video element when the DOM loaded. Neither of which worked.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
<video id="movie1" class="movie" width="434" controls >
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"/>
    <source src="video/vid1.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <source src="video/vid1.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
    <source src="video/vid1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <object data="video/vid1.mp4" width="434"></object>
    Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 videos, we're sorry. <br/>
    Try switching your browser to view the videos.
</video>
<video id="movie2" class="movie" width="434" controls >
    <source src="video/vid2.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <source src="video/vid2.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
    <source src="video/vid2.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <object data="video/vid2.mp4" width="434"></object>
    Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 videos, we're sorry. <br/>
    Try switching your browser to view the videos.
</video>
<video id="movie3" class="movie" width="434" controls >
    <source src="video/vid3.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <source src="video/vid3.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video/vid3.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <object data="video/vid3.mp4" width="434"></object>
    Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 videos, we're sorry. <br/>
    Try switching your browser to view the videos.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the `object` element, which does not seem to be required anymore these days. Works fine without it!